# How to run single instance of goroutine

Tags: go, thread-safety, goroutine

I have a goroutine that will be run multiple times. But it can only run one at a time (single instance). What is the correct/idiomatic way to make sure a certain goroutine can run only one at a time?

Here is my contrived example code to illustrate the point:

```
func main() {
    // Contrived example!!!!!!
    // theCaller() may be run at multiple, unpredictable times
    // theJob() must only be run one at a time
    go theCaller()
    go theCaller()
    go theCaller()
}

func theCaller() {
    if !jobIsRunning { // race condition here!
        jobIsRunning = true
        go theJob()
    }
}

var jobIsRunning bool

// Can run multiple times, but only one at a time
func theJob() {
    defer jobDone()
    do_something()
}

func jobDone() {
    jobIsRunning = false
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/ take a look at mutexes.

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight too

Comment: Thanks JimB I wasn't aware of `singleflight`. I'd have to study it as the example they offer seems quite complicated. One immediate show-stopper however is the comment that says "If a duplicate comes in, the duplicate caller waits for the
// original to complete". If the goroutine is already running, I just need the others to say make no attempt to run it again.

Comment: This does feel a bit like an X-Y problem to me... why would you use routines, but force them to run sequentially (essentially turning your concurrent process into a sequential one?). Depending on what you're doing, you could easily use a channel, though

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I don't want them to run sequential. That implies blocking & queueing. I want subsequent attempts to run the goroutine to just realize it is already running and no need to do anything and proceed from there.

Comment: @Michael: I have to ask: why are you trying to solve the problem at the side of the routine? Why is there a chance that the same job gets fired off multiple times? To me, this still has the feel of an X-Y problem, and I've got a feeling like the issue might be with the code that fires off the job instead

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Because the job gets triggered from events coming from the network where I can't be certain that the event won't be lost or duplicated.

Comment: You want jobs to fail? But on the other hand, you surely do not want to have your events silently dropped, correct? So, to get this straight: there are events coming in, you want to process them one at a time in a goroutine (why - [concurrency is not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism)) and the others to be queued up, either internally or externally, say in Kafka or some sort of MQ?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg "You want jobs to fail." No, I want them to succeed, which is why I don't want them running on top of each other and clobbering the other's work. No, I don't want to process them one at a time, I want the first one to run and the others to not step on it. And I don't want them queued up because I only need them to succeed once.

Comment: Define „not step on it“. Either, job x+1 ought to be queued for later processing while job x is running or it ought to be discarded.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg It ought to be discarded. As I've said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on question and other comments from the OP, it looks like the goal is to start a new job if and only if a job is not already running.

Use a boolean variable protected by a [sync.Mutex](https://godoc.org/sync#Mutex) to record the running state of of the job. Set the variable to true when starting a job and to false when the job completes. Test this variable to determine if a job should be started.

```
var (
    jobIsRunning   bool
    JobIsrunningMu sync.Mutex
)

func maybeStartJob() {
    JobIsrunningMu.Lock()
    start := !jobIsRunning
    jobIsRunning = true
    JobIsrunningMu.Unlock()
    if start {
        go func() {
            theJob()
            JobIsrunningMu.Lock()
            jobIsRunning = false
            JobIsrunningMu.Unlock()
        }()
    }
}

func main() {
    maybeStartJob()
    maybeStartJob()
    maybeStartJob()
}
```

The lower-level [sync/atomic](https://godoc.org/sync/atomic) package can also be used and may have better performance than using a mutex.

```
var jobIsRunning uint32

func maybeStartJob() {
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&jobIsRunning, 0, 1) {
        go func() {
            theJob()
            atomic.StoreUint32(&jobIsRunning, 0)
        }()
    }
}
```

The sync/atomic package documentation warns that the functions in the package require great care to use correctly and that most applications should use the sync package.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this does what I need as `JobIsrunningMu.Lock()` blocks in `maybeStartJob()`. I can't have `maybeStartJob()` being blocked because it is event-driven and not fully under my control.

Comment: That's the problem I came up against as almost everything in the `sync` package is a blocking call.

Comment: @ThunderCat do you need that `jobIsRunning` flag if you have a lock on the func? The example seems a bit overcomplicated for this. Wouldn't something like this be enough to ensure that the job's content is executed only by one goroutine at a time while also allowing it to be concurrently "queued" by multiple goroutines? https://play.golang.org/p/stmhNkl2h-d

Comment: @Michael can you take a look at the link in the above comment, does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Michael maybeStartJob blocks for the time it takes to check the flag. That's unlikely be an issue in the application.

Comment: @ThunderCat Unfortunately it is a problem. The job func might be long running. What I need is for the first attempt to start the job to succeed. Then all others while job is running to just fail (job is running, no need to run it again, proceed). I don't need them to block or queue. I'm trying to achieve what we typically do with lock files in shell scripts ... lock file exists, exit, no need to do anything.

Comment: @Michael  The anwer does exactly what you describe in your comment. The `maybeStartJob` function does not block on execution of the job.  The function either exits because a job is already running or starts the job in a goroutine.  The function does use a mutex and there can be contention on that mutex with other callers to `maybeStartJob` and the job cleanup code. The contention is unlikely to be an issue because the mutex is only held while accessing `isJobRunning`.

Comment: @ThunderCat Ah, I see now. The lock is very quick and dependent on nothing external. I think that could work.

Comment: I think the bool is unnecessary here. The mutex can well be used instead. Lock it at he beginning of the job, unlock it after completion.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Can't do that. The job can be very long running and I can't have the others blocked waiting for it to finish, they have other work to do.